# How to insert records in loop in MySQL based on results from another table

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have a TableA from where I would like some information for e.g. tableA has columns `**name, age and rollNo**` and I would like to insert `**age**` and `**rollNo**` from tableA to tableB wherever the age is greater than 20 and rollNo less than 500

Is there anyway this can be done in MySQL using a procedure or something.

Comment: "Insert records in a loop" is always a bad idea. This can be done in a single statement.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ sometimes it is unavoidable. In such cases, a stored procedure making use of CURSORs is the only way to go if it must be done on the server.

Comment: @Uueerdo: I guess I don't know how powerful MySQL's query syntax is -- I have never used a CURSOR in T-SQL, for example (instead, WHILE loops are fantastic). You can almost always write a loop without a CURSOR, even if CURSOR is the easy way out. Stuff like that should be a last resort (in my humble opinion, of course).

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ You still need to loop through cursor results in MySQL stored procs. It's not an instead thing; just what you use to be able to iterate through results within a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a single query using the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (Age, RollNo)
SELECT Age, RollNo
FROM TableA
WHERE Age > 20 AND RollNo < 500
```

Comment: @Cory I had to make a few modifications but worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.